# Latex not render when string call from javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, latex, rendering, tex

In my below code:

```js
function test() {
 document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML="$$\left[ x=0 \right] $$";//same code from demo1.but not rendered

}
test();
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://latex.codecogs.com/latexit.js"></script>

<p lang="latex"id="demo"></p>
<p lang="latex"id="demo1">$$\left[ x=0 \right] $$</p>
```

Same code applied from javascript. Its not rendering.kindly tell Whats wrong with my code & correct my code or give any alter suggestion for that .

Thanks in advance

Comment: [Javascript is not Java](http://i.stack.imgur.com/ocTlb.png)

Comment: @BackSlash Thank's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript consider [\r as Carriage Return] so you have to use \\right.

```js
function test() { document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML="$$\\left[ x=0 \\right] $$";
}
test();
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://latex.codecogs.com/latexit.js"></script>

<p lang="latex"id="demo"></p>
<p lang="latex"id="demo1">$$\left[ x=0 \right] $$</p>
```