# Regex match with '\' slash and replace with '\\'?

Tags: javascript, html, regex, tex

I was converting normal string in to latex format.So i was created the latex  code match and replace the `\` single slash into `\\` double slash.why the i need it Refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39696835/latex-not-render-when-string-call-from-javascript/39697157#39697157).I tried Below code :

```js
function test(){
  var tex="$$\left[ x=\left({{11}\over{2}}+{{\sqrt{3271}}\over{2\,3^{{{3}\over{2} $$";
   var tex_form = tex.replace("/[\\\/\\\\\.\\\\]/g", "\\");
  document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML=tex_form;//nothing get
  }
test();
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Not getting any output data.But the match in this [link](https://regex101.com/r/yO1xI6/1)

i wish to need replace the `\` into `\\`

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98149/why-is-it-considered-rude-to-say-thanks-in-advance

Comment: There are no slashes in your string to convert: http://jsbin.com/vividihaze/1/edit?js,console

Comment: no,see the `var tex` `\` are there

Comment: @prasad — You are confusing your source code with your string.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10041998/get-backslashes-inside-a-string-javascript

Comment: @Quentin where is the `\`  slash.i was applied in this var tex field.and why the \ slash are hidden from the result

Comment: @prasad — Combined with whatever characters followed it into an escape sequence and consumed by the JavaScript compiler.

Comment: @Quentin.ok then how solve my problem.There is no way?

Comment: @prasad — I gave you an answer half an hour ago.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> why the i need it

As the question you link to says, the `\` character has special meaning inside a JavaScript string literal. It represents [an escape sequence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String#Escape_notation).

> Not getting any output data.But the match in this link

The escape sequence is processed when the string literal is parsed by the JavaScript compiler.

By the time you apply your regular expression to them, they have been consumed. The slash characters only exist in your source code, not in your data.

If you want to put a slash character in your string, then you need to write the escape sequence for it (the `\\`) in *the source code*. You can't add them back in with JavaScript afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

There are these issues:

1. The string literal has no backslashes;
2. The regular expression is not a regular expression;
3. The class in the intended regular expression cannot match *sequences*, only single characters;
4. The replacement would not *add* backslashes, only replace with them.

Here you find the details on each point:

#### 1. How to Encode Backslashes in String Literals

Your `tex` variable has no backslashes. This is because a backslash in a string literal is not taken as a literal backslash, but as an escape for interpreting the character that follows it.

When you have `"$$\left..."`, then the `\l` means *"literal l"*, and so the content of your variable will be:

```
$$left...
```

As an `l` does not need to be escaped, the backslash is completely unnecessary, and these two assignments result in the *same* string value:

```
var tex="$$\left[ x=\left({{11}\over{2}}+{{\sqrt{3271}}\over{2\,3^{{{3}\over{2} $$";

var tex="$$left[ x=left({{11}over{2}}+{{sqrt{3271}}over{2,3^{{{3}over{2} $$";
```

To bring the point home, this will *also* represent the same value:

```
var tex="\$\$\l\e\f\t\[\ \x\=\l\e\f\t\(\{\{\1\1\}\o\v\e\r\{\2\}\}\+\{\{\s\q\r\t\{\3\2\7\1\}\}\o\v\e\r\{\2\,\3\^\{\{\{\3\}\o\v\e\r\{\2\}\ \$\$";
```

If you really want to have literal backslashes in your content (which I understand you do, as this is about LaTeX), then you need to escape each of those backslashes... with a backslash:

```
var tex="$$\\left[ x=\\left({{11}\\over{2}}+{{\\sqrt{3271}}\\over{2\\,3^{{{3}\\over{2} $$";
```

Now the content of your `tex` variable will be this string:

```
$$\left[ x=\left({{11}\over{2}}+{{\sqrt{3271}}\over{2\,3^{{{3}\over{2} $$
```

#### 2. How to Code Regular Expression Literals

You are passing a *string* literal to the first argument of `replace`, while you really intend to pass a regular expression literal. You should leave out the quotes for that to happen. The `/` are the delimiters of a regular expression literal, not quotes:

```
/[\\\/\\\\\.\\\\]/g
```

This should *not* be wrapped in quotes. JavaScript understands the `/` delimiters as denoting a regular expression literal, including the optional modifiers at the end (like `g` here).

#### 3. Classes are sets of single characters

This regular expression has unnecessary characters. The class `[...]` should list all *individual* characters you want to match. Currently you have these characters (after resolving the escapes):

```
\
/
\
\
.
\
\
```

It is overkill to have the backslash represented 5 times. Also, in JavaScript the forward slash and dot do not need to be escaped when occurring in a class. So the above regular expression is equivalent to this one:

```
/[\\/.]/g
```

Maybe this is, or is not, what you intended to match. To match several sequences of characters, you could use the `|` operator. This is just an example:

```
/\\\\|\\\/|\\\./g
```

... but I don't think you need this.

#### 4. How to actually prefix with backslashes

It seems strange to me that you would want to replace a point or forward slash with a backslash. Probably you want to *prefix* those with a backslash. In that case make a capture group (with parentheses) and refer to it with `$1` in this `replace`:

```
tex.replace(/([\\/.])/g, "\\$1");
```

Note again, that in the replacement string there is only one literal backslash, as the first one is an escape (see point 1 above).

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if I understood the problem, but try this code:

```
var tex_form = tex.replace("/(\\)/g","\\\\");.
```

You need to use `'(' ')'` instead of `'['']'` to get a match for output.